# JAVA API , JERSEY / POST not working

Tags: java, api, jersey

So I have in my code POST method :

```
 @POST
      @Path("/send/{userPost}")
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces("application/json")
          public Response sendUser(@PathParam("userPost") String userPost ) {
           List<Post>userPosts = new ArrayList();
            Post post = new Post(99,userPost,"Bartek Szlapa");
            userPosts.add(post);
            User user = new User(99,"Bartek","Szlapa",userPosts);

              String output = user.toString();
              return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

          }
```

unfortunately its not working. I'm getting 404 error. Server is configured correctly because other methods work perfectly. Funny thing is that when I remove {userPost} , parameter : @PathParam("userPost") String userPost and send empty request : http://localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send it works - I'm getting new User object with null at some fields. Do you know why I cannot send parameter ? Thanks in advance for help! :)

Comment: what is the request you are trying?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send?=test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are sending is not a path parameter to send your value as a path parameter based on your api , let us say you are trying to send "test"

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send/test
```

if you want to use query params

```
@POST
  @Path("/send")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces("application/json")
      public Response sendUser(@QueryParam("userPost") String userPost ) {
```

and your request should be

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send?userPost=test
```

Answer (score 1):

Your "userPost" parameter is not in the Path : localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send?=test

You defined this path :

```
@Path("/send/{userPost}")
```

So, your URI should be :

```
localhost:8080/JavaAPI/rest/api/send/test
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not in the Path ? I think it is ... :)